# USB barcode scanner and Arduino

Tags: arduino, rs232, usb-device

I have a [USB barcode scanner](http://www.barcodesinc.com/honeywell/ms9540.htm) and I have difficulty getting the data out of it. What I did was to get [one of these adapters](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/993300/BELKIN-PS2-USB-ADAPTER-BUCHSESTECKER/0410119&ref=list), and followed [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-portable-barcode-scanner-with-an-arduino-an/?ALLSTEPS) with no luck. When I connect the ports as shown, it does not even power up the scanner to make a BEEP. With computer it works as a PS2 keyboard I guess without problem.

Any recommendation on how I can go forward?

Answer (score 3):

That seems to be a USB scanner. It mentions in the instructable that it won't work for USB:

> While I started this project with the intent of "let's use that old CueCat" I couldn't ac-tually find mine, so I bought a "new" one off of ebay.  When purchasing one, it is extremely important that you get one of the original PS2 models.  Some of the ones for sale at places like library thing are USB and those WILL NOT WORK with this project

If your intention is to talk to the Arduino, you would either need to use one with USB host capabilities (don't know if they exist as I have not used one) or RS232 (mentioned as supported by the scanner - the serial connection [here](http://www.barcodesinc.com/support/connections.htm)) which would be a lot easier, just use the Arduino UART connection.
So, I think if you get an RJ45 to 9-pin serial cable, plug the RJ45 into scanner and the 9-pin female into a 9-pin male (may need MAX232 depending on signal levels, may be able to pug straight into Arduino if it uses same logic levels) it should work. There should be plenty of Arduino tutorials on using UART/RS232 and (if needed) MAX232.

Comment: RJ45 or RJ11? Which is it?